# How do I create functions in javascript using values from a dropdown list?

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to create a function using the dropdown values in html like so

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Taxi Fare</title>
        <center><h1>Taxi Fare</h1>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">    
        <script>
            function myAddition(){
                var NorthAvenue = 0;
                var QuezonAvenue = 4;
                var GMAKamuning = 5;
                var $sum = (40) + (place2 - place1) * (14);
                    window.alert("The sum is: " + $sum);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body class="bg-warning">
        <center>
        <form method="post">
    <select id="place1" name="place1">
        <option value="NorthAvenue">North Avenue</option>
        <option value="QuezonAvenue">Quezon Ave</option>
        <option value="GMAKamuning">GMA Kamuning</option>
    </select>
</form>
<form method="post">
    <select id="place2" name="place2">
        <option value="NorthAvenue">North Avenue</option>
        <option value="QuezonAvenue">Quezon Ave</option>
        <option value="GMAKamuning">GMA Kamuning</option>
    </select>
            <button type="button" onclick="myAddition(place2,place1)">Compute Fare</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

but it always returns "the sum is NaN" just confused as to what is wrong here

Comment: NaN stand for "Not a number". It appears that you are trying to subtract strings of text which would, in fact, not return a number.

Comment: oh i see now thank you for the answer

Comment: how would you suggest i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

In your script function put two parameters like this `function myAddition(place2,place1)` and change value of select tags from text to number like this
        `<select id="place1" name="place1">
            <option value="0">North Avenue</option>
            <option value="4">Quezon Ave</option>
            <option value="5">GMA Kamuning</option>
        </select>
        <select id="place2" name="place2">
            <option value="0">North Avenue</option>
            <option value="4">Quezon Ave</option>
            <option value="5">GMA Kamuning</option>
        </select>
        <button type="button" onclick="myAddition(document.getElementById('place2').value,document.getElementById('place1').value)">Compute Fare</button>`
Please try your code in this way

Comment: You were sending text values to your function and that's why it was giving NaN and most importantly you were not initializing and declaring place2 and place1 values in myAddition Function thats why it was giving you error.

Comment: Pleasure is all mine @LyellMarkus

Answer (score 0):

You were placing a **html select object** into a expression , what you have to do is to place the value of that html element that is select element using value property(**place1.value** and **place2.value**) and when it will be evaluated in a expression it will be acting as a string untill you evaluate it by using the eval function.Your code can be improved.Refer to other answers to improve the code , i have solved it in your way.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Taxi Fare</title>
        <center><h1>Taxi Fare</h1>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">    
        <script>
            function myAddition(){
                var NorthAvenue = 0;
                var QuezonAvenue = 4;
                var GMAKamuning = 5;
                var $sum = (40) + (eval(place2.value) - eval(place1.value)) * (14);
                    window.alert("The sum is: " + $sum);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body class="bg-warning">
        <center>
        <form method="post">
    <select id="place1" name="place1">
        <option value="NorthAvenue">North Avenue</option>
        <option value="QuezonAvenue">Quezon Ave</option>
        <option value="GMAKamuning">GMA Kamuning</option>
    </select>
</form>
<form method="post">
    <select id="place2" name="place2">
        <option value="NorthAvenue">North Avenue</option>
        <option value="QuezonAvenue">Quezon Ave</option>
        <option value="GMAKamuning">GMA Kamuning</option>
    </select>
            <button type="button" onclick="myAddition()">Compute Fare</button>
    </body>
</html>
```